# Why my arrays are still empty after I push into them?

Tags: arrays, node.js

```
socket.on("map-input", function(data) {
      let notename = data.notename;
      let locations = [];
      let coordinates = [];
      let coordinatesOBJ = [];

      Note.findOne({notename:notename}).then(noteFound => {
        locations = noteFound.locations;
        const sortedLocations = locations.slice().sort((a,b) => a.date - b.date)
        const n = sortedLocations.length;
        for(let i = 0;i < n; i++){
          geocoder.geocode(sortedLocations[i].location)
          .then(results => { 
                 coordinatesOBJ.push(results);
                 return coordinatesOBJ;
          })
          .then(obj => {
            for(let k = 0;k < obj.length; k++) {
               for(let m = 0; m < obj[k].length; m++) {
                 return {
                   lat: obj[k][m].latitude,
                   lng: obj[k][m].longitude
                 }
               }
            }
          })
          .then(res => {
            coordinates.push(res);
          })
        }

     console.log(coordinates);
     socket.emit('map-output',coordinates);

      })
  });
```

Here I tried to get some locations from database and convert them to latitude and longitude, then to send them to the client side for a map.

But the arrays coordinates and coordinatesOBJ are still empty after i push values into them. Can you please look up after this and tell me what I did wrong? I declared them empty, because for every reload of the page the initial array must be empty for not overwritting.  Thank you

Comment: Is this really how you format your code?

Comment: It is relevant? I like to work progressive, if you have a hint please tell me how should I format it

Comment: Yes, it is relevant. You are asking us to donate our weekend time, to give you your solution, for free. The least you could do is spend a couple of moments tidying up your code so that it looks nice, and is nice and easy to read for us. Besides, _you_ will also find it easier to read, and therefore easier not to make mistakes.

Comment: ok, let me format it and i will come back with an edit

Comment: Good stuff, thanks.

Comment: done, i hope it's readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

> The Promise object represents the **eventual** completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.

you should wait for all `geocoder.geocode(...)` promises to complete and only then return the `coordinates`.

you might consider [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

> The `Promise.all()` method returns a single Promise that resolves when **all** of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

now that you know the issue of you code, you should be able to fix it. if you are still struggeling, let me know and i will update the answer.

Comment: I don't know where I have to put that Promise.all() after geocoder.geocode(...) ?